# Smart page breaks to make chapters print modularly

Tags: latex, lyx

I'm writing a booklet for my debate club in LyX, and it is a collection of Prep Cases - each prep case is a chapter. Currently I have a "new page" after every chapter, but I want something more - I want to make sure chapters begin in odd numbered pages, so that when I print the whole booklet in duplex - each prep case will be a standalone, separable unit. Is that possible in LyX or plain LaTeX?

---

**Edit**: silly me. I meant to say sections and not chapters. Is this possible with sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this in Lyx, but if it will let you  slip in some raw LaTeX, put this in your preamble:

```
\let\originalsection=\section
\renewcommand\section{\par\cleardoublepage\originalsection}
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally, this is done using the `openright` option on the document class. This causes `\chapter` to use [`\cleardoublepage`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_103.html) internally, thus starting on an odd page.

You can also use `\cleardoublepage` manually instead but just using the option is more convenient.

Comment: What do I write in the preamble to get it to use the `openright` option?

Comment: I found where to add the option to the document class in LyX, I added `openright`, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Amir: since you’re apparently using sections instead of chapters, the option doesn’t work – use `\cleardoublepage` before a new section. Or think about moving to a document class that supports chapters.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Exam class (based on Article) and I got this to work in LyX 2.2 with the following:

- **Document>Document Settings>Page Layout>Two-sided document**
- **Insert>Formatting>Clear Double Page** whenever you want to force a part of your document to start on an odd-numbered page.